# Adjusting Binary Logistic Formula in SPSS

Tags: binary, controls, formula, regression, spss

I am running a binary logistic regression in SPSS, to test the effect of e.g. TV advertisements on the probability of a consumer to buy a product. My problem is that with the formula of binary logistic regression:

```
P=1/(1+e^(-(a+b*Adv)) )
```

the maximum probability will be equal to 100%. However,even if I increase the number of advertisements by 1000, it is not sensible to assume that the probability to purchase will be 100%. So if I draw the graph of the logistic regression with the coefficients from the Binary Logistic Regression, at some point the probability reaches 100%, which is never the case in a real life setting. How can I control for that?

Is there a way to change the SPSS binary logistic regression to have a maximum probability of e.g. 20%?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum hypothetical probability is 100%, but if you use real-world data, your model will fit the data in such a way that the predicted y-value for any given value of x will be no higher than the real-world y-value (+/- your model's error term). I wouldn't worry too much about the hypothetical maximum probability as long as my model fit the data reasonably well. One of the key reasons for using logistic regressions instead of OLS linear regressions is to avoid impossible predicted values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This enlightens me a bit. What I am worried about however, is that managers also want to be able to foresee what happens if they increase their number of advertisements. So according to the graph one would wrongly presume that by increasing his ads by e.g. 200 then the probability that a consumer will buy will be 70%. However, I believe that no matter the number of advertisements, the probability will never be above 20-30%. So I am looking for a way to control for that.